# Intuit IPP QBO API Overwriting Customer's Default Tax Code when sending TaxCodeRef on Invoice

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

- In the Quickbooks Online (QBO) web application, you can specify the
  Default Tax Code for that customer
- When you create an invoice, and mark the line items as taxable ("TAX"), and do NOT specify a transaction tax code ref, QBO will nicely apply the Default Tax Code to that invoice and calculate the correct tax accordingly.
- However, if you specify a transaction Tax Code Ref in an invoice, though the imported invoice in QBO uses that tax code and correctly calculates the taxes, it is also **permanently updating the Customer's Default Tax Code** in the customer profile.

Anyone know if this is a bug? Or if the way I am passing the tax code ref on the invoice is the issue?

Here is my Invoice creation XML that I post to the API:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Invoice xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
  <CustomField>
    <DefinitionId>1</DefinitionId>
    <Type>StringType</Type>
    <StringValue>15129</StringValue>
  </CustomField>
  <CustomField>
    <DefinitionId>2</DefinitionId>
    <Type>StringType</Type>
    <StringValue>13553</StringValue>
  </CustomField>
  <DocNumber>9316-O</DocNumber>
  <TxnDate>2016-05-12-06:00</TxnDate>
  <PrivateNote>15129 / Acme </PrivateNote>
  <Line>
    <LineNum>1</LineNum>
    <Description>Project: Acme </Description>
    <DetailType>DescriptionOnly</DetailType>
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <LineNum>2</LineNum>
    <Description>Part: 74827 - 8 ea. Down Rod and link 810 x 23 of:
1" x .25 wall alum. tubing;
Zinc plated R hand Threaded Clevis ;
Zinc plated L hand Threaded Clevis ;;

Part: 74830 - 8 ea. Down Rod and link 944 x 27.4375 of:
1" x .25 wall alum. tubing;
Zinc plated R hand Threaded Clevis ;
Zinc plated L hand Threaded Clevis ;;

Part: 74829 - 4 ea. Down Rod and link 943 x 24.8125 of:
1" x .25 wall alum. tubing;
Zinc plated R hand Threaded Clevis ;
Zinc plated L hand Threaded Clevis ;;

Part: 74831 - 20 ea. Link x 7.7 of:
Aluminum Mill 5052 .250Ga.;;

</Description>
    <Amount>1387.63000000</Amount>
    <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
    <SalesItemLineDetail>
      <ItemRef>19</ItemRef>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
      <TaxCodeRef>TAX</TaxCodeRef>
    </SalesItemLineDetail>
  </Line>
  <TxnTaxDetail>
    <TxnTaxCodeRef>5</TxnTaxCodeRef>
  </TxnTaxDetail>
  <CustomerRef>423</CustomerRef>
  <PrintStatus>NeedToPrint</PrintStatus>
  <EmailStatus>NeedToSend</EmailStatus>
  <BillEmail>
    <Address>test@test.com</Address>
  </BillEmail>
</Invoice>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

- We have 2 tax codes setup in QBO
- If the customer's default tax code is set to the **first** tax code option in the drop down list (DDL). And you create a new invoice, or send an update to an existing invoice that specify the Transaction Tax Code Ref that corresponds to **2nd tax code** in the DDL in the UI, t**hen the customer's default tax code is incorrectly updated** to that second tax code, like stated above.
- However, if in the UI you set the Customer's Default Tax Code to the **second** tax code in the DDL, then send a new or updated invoice with a Transaction Tax Code Ref of the **first** tax code in the DDL, the customer's Default Tax Code is **NOT updated**...it stays as the 2nd tax code.
- List item

Answer (score -2):

Please reference the following thread and answer:

https://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com/questions/1372819-customer-default-tax-code-being-overwritten-by-invoice-transaction-tax-code-ref

Comment: This is not an answer and does not link to anything relevant?